# ActionBar Tab Listener

Tags: xamarin.android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have a simple layout with an ActionBar and I would like to show a message when a user selects a tab. I've implemented ActionBar.ITabListener and OnTabSelected but it doesn't work. What is wrong with the code?
Here's the code:

```
namespace ICSTabs

    {
        [Activity (Label = "ICSTabs", MainLauncher = true)]
        public class Activity1 : Activity, ActionBar.ITabListener
        {


            protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate (bundle);

                // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
                SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

                ActionBar bar = ActionBar;

                bar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;

                bar.AddTab (bar.NewTab ().SetText ("TEXT1")
                            .SetTabListener (this));
                bar.AddTab (bar.NewTab ().SetText ("TEXT2")
                            .SetTabListener (this));
                bar.AddTab (bar.NewTab ().SetText ("TEXT3")
                            .SetTabListener (this));


            }

            public void OnTabSelected (ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Some text", ToastLength.Short);
            }

            public void OnTabUnselected (ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
            {
            }

            public void OnTabReselected (ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
            {
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After constructing a `Toast` object, you need to call the `show()` method to actually display the Toast. Here is the code.

```
public void OnTabSelected (ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Some text", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

Comment: Show and tell, please! Currently you're just showing us how this answers the problem.